# Unknown column 'name_last' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

After researching this error, I find it mainly is occuring due to the back ticks reserved for column names. I do not have any of these back ticks!
I also removed all the code up to the offending code (apparently in my games_home.php file)

Here is my MySQL Database table structure:
id, division, name, member_paid, team, capt, nic, mf, ranking, address, email1, email2, phone1, phone2

Here is what is left in my code that I have not removed trying to track this error down.

```
                include("../sparkplug4.php");

            //Calculates the games played by each home team player

            // Variable $allplayersHome stores all the players ID numbers in an array (comma delimited list)
            $allplayersHome = array("$playerH1", "$playerH2", "$playerH3", "$playerH4", "$playerH5", "$playerH6", "$playerH7", "$playerH8", "$playerH9", "$playerH10", "$playerH11", "$playerH12", "$playerH13", "$playerH14", "$playerH15", "$playerH16", "$playerH17", "$playerH18", "$playerH19", "$playerH20", "$playerH21", "$playerH22", "$playerH23", "$playerH24", "$playerH25", "$playerH26", "$playerH27", "$playerH28", "$playerH29", "$playerH30", "$playerH31", "$playerH32");

            // Variable $keysH1 contains how many times playerH1 played in all the matches (and so on..)
            $keysH1 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH1");
            $keysH2 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH2");
            $keysH3 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH3");
            $keysH4 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH4");
            $keysH5 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH5");
            $keysH6 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH6");
            $keysH7 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH7");
            $keysH8 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH8");
            $keysH9 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH9");
            $keysH10 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH10");
            $keysH11 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH11");
            $keysH12 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH12");
            $keysH13 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH13");
            $keysH14 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH14");
            $keysH15 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH15");
            $keysH16 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH16");
            $keysH17 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH17");
            $keysH18 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH18");
            $keysH19 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH19");
            $keysH20 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH20");
            $keysH21 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH21");
            $keysH22 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH22");
            $keysH23 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH23");
            $keysH24 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH24");
            $keysH25 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH25");
            $keysH26 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH26");
            $keysH27 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH27");
            $keysH28 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH28");
            $keysH29 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH29");
            $keysH30 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH30");
            $keysH31 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH31");
            $keysH32 = array_keys($allplayersHome, "$playerH32");

            $homeplayer1 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH1' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer2 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH2' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer3 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH3' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer4 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH4' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer5 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH5' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer6 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH6' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer7 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH7' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer8 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH8' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer9 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH9' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer10 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH10' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error());

            $homeplayer11 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH11' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer12 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH12' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer13 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH13' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer14 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH14' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer15 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH15' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer16 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH16' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer17 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH17' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer18 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH18' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer19 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH19' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer20 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH20' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error());

            $homeplayer21 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH21' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer22 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH22' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer23 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH23' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer24 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH24' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer25 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH25' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer26 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH26' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer27 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH27' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer28 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH28' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer29 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH29' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer30 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH30' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error());

            $homeplayer31 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH31' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $homeplayer32 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM member_data2015spring WHERE id = '$playerH32' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 

            echo "<strong>Total Games Played By Home Team:</strong><br />";
```

Comment: Most likely the code you were posting are not fitting to mentioned error message.

Comment: Could you show us your table schema? And also, where do you reference `name_last` in any query?

Comment: Why do you have so many queries? Wouldn't 1 query do? Plus, the usual caveats about deprecated APIs and the use of prepared statements

Comment: name_last "WAS" a column a few years back and I have changed that column to name only. I did a search in my main folder for name_last and changed them all to name (and removed name_first too). Now that I've said that, it reminds me that the last problem I had was because Dreamweaver 'said' it had uploaded files, when indeed it had not. Im going to reupload the directory using filezille ... brb.

Comment: how do I show you my schema? it says 412 charters too much. Also I taught myself PHP in order to create this monstrosity. It was working in its entirety until I choose to embed it within a Joomla article.

Comment: Here's a better to understand this issue: the last line in my process.php after hitting submit process.php calls up a lot of my includes. The last include is creating the error. include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/ewms/inc/games_home.php'); I stripped games_home.php of EVERYTHING except an echo statement. When going directly to the games_home.php (bypassing the form) it shows the echo. But I am still receiving the [[Unknown column 'name_last' in 'field list']] error when using the form. Error disapears when I remove the include to the games_home.php.

Comment: sfda.org/sfda2014/includes/ewms/inc/games_home.php